# In Camel how to pass an xml node to a method in a class

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an xml node that I have parsed from an xml file with the following code

```
    File file = new File("test.xml");
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
    NodeList configNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("connector");
    Node configNode = configNodeList.item(0);
```

I have to pass congigNode to a method in another class.
The project is in Camel, and I have to test a Class which has a method which accepts the configNode as input.
Do I add configNode in the sendBody of the ProducerTemplate

```
template.sendBody("");
```

or somewhere in the routebuilder

```
             from("direct:start")
             .to("mock:result");
```

I am new to Camel and am having a hard time. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To process a selected node of the XML file, you can write a route like the one below:

```
    from("file://test.xml?noop=true") //Read your xml
    .setBody().xpath("//connector/node()")       //select NodeList by xpath
    .split(body()) //Split list - below working with one Node
    .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true") // print all data to log
    //below must be a processing of your node, maybe the data type conversion before that
    .bean(new YourBean(), "methodName");
```